# How to return a blade component from a controller action in laravel

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-blade

I have a controller which create and save a post into the database and I use this endpoint in my javascript and I want to return a blade component by passing this created model to the component class.
Is there a way to do that ?
thanks.

Comment: I think you are talking or needing [Laravel Livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com), but I don't like it, it is disgusting, you have to learn JS and PHP and do it with Vue/React/Angular or even vanilla JS

Answer (score 1):

You can render blade components (output an HTML string) using the `View` facade.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // store stuff ...
    
    return response()->json([
        'html' => View::make('path.to.blade', [...params...])->render()
    ], 200);
}
```

```json
{
    html: '<div>...</div>'
}
```